# Adding gradient to TextFormField's border

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

Is it possible to add gradient to TextFormField's border in Flutter? I want to achieve something like this: [wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFhWO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a simple trick, just wrap a TextFormField and a Container in a Column and set the Container background color as gradient. Here is an example

```
Container(
              width: 200,
              height: 60,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                    decoration: new InputDecoration(
                        border: InputBorder.none,
                        focusedBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        enabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        disabledBorder: InputBorder.none,
                        contentPadding:
                        EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, bottom: 5, top: 11, right: 15),
                        hintText: "Moje imie"),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 2,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                          colors: [Colors.red, Colors.blue],
                          begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
                          end: const FractionalOffset(0.5, 0.0),
                          stops: [0.0, 1.0],
                          tileMode: TileMode.clamp
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            )
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Thank you very much sir! For begin and end I would rather use`begin: Alignment.centerLeft, end: Alignment.centerRight,`